# Reading files from specific folder which has got datetime stamp- sas

Tags: sas

I have to read csv files every day which are kept in a folder with a date time stamp on it. eg: newfolder20150430023210

I have to extract these files everyday from the folder. But since the folder has got time stamp on it, I'm unable to create a macro which can read the latest file from the directory. I could create a macro of the current datetime but not the folder datetime.

eg: path:- D:\SAS\Data\Newfolder20150430023210\file.csv I need to read this path where   20150430023210 is dynamic.

thank you

Comment: Hi Bharath, it's not clear to me which is the exact process you want to implement. You don't want to scan the directory relative to the current day, do you? You'd like to consider a range of dates? Add some detail please.

Comment: @DaBigNikoladze I want to read the latest folder first. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to find the newest folder first, this code wil do that:

```
filename f pipe "dir /B/A:D/O:-D D:\SAS\Data\Newfolder*";
data _null_;
  infile f;
  input;
  call symputx("lastDir",_infile_);
  stop;
run;
```

Now, you have a macrovariable "lastDir" that has the name of the folder.

Comment: Yes!! That's exactly what I want. Thank you.